# Matching up to a pattern

Tags: regex, python-2.7, csv, file-io

Good Morning All,

I am currently reading in a text file that takes the following form:

```
foo: example1
bar: example2
fizz: buzz
abra: cadabra
```

and outputting a csv in the following format:

```
foo,bar,fizz,abra
example1,example2,buzz,cadabra
```

However, there are some edge cases for "abra" where my text file takes the following form:

```
foo: example1
bar: example2
fizz: buzz
abra: cadabra
something else
another thing
(new line)
probably another thing
(new line)
some number
```

This pattern repeats multiple times, I read in the text file, and generate the csv.  I do so by create a dictionary where the keys are the header and the values are what corresponds to the text after the headers; therefore:

```
myDict = {'foo': ['example1', ..., 'last foo in txt file'], 'bar': ['example2', ... 'last bar in txt file'], ... , 'abra': ['cadabra'], ..., 'last abra in txt file']}
```

I use the csv.DictWriter method to write my csv.  However, I am currently using a loop as followed:

```
with open(txtFile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # create lists that maps to header keys
```

This works great, well if there were only one line of txt after 'abra'.  So, in order to concatenate values in the 'abra' list from

```
abraList = ['cadabra', 'something different', '\n', probably another thing', '\n', 'some number']
```

and change it to:

```
abraList = ['cadabra something different', '\n', probably another thing', '\n', 'some number']
```

I use the following:

```
out = []
for i,e in enumerate(abraList):
    if e in string.whitespace:
        out.append(e)
    else:
        if 0!=i and out[-1][0] not in string.whitespace:
            out.append(out.pop() + ' ' + e)
        else:
            out.append(e)
```

Could someone help me find a way to to just match all values after 'abra' and before the pattern starts again with 'foo'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need the newlines, the simplest way is to just join the list and split it again:

```
out = ' '.join(abraList).replace(' \n', '\n').replace('\n ', '\n').split('\n')
```